# Use of Preferred-Value in Language Tag Records of Type "Variant" (RFC 5646)

Tags: iana, rfc5646

In [RFC 5646, Tags for Identifying Languages, § 3.1.2 Record and Field Definitions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646#section-3.1.2), the following explanation is given for the semantics of the Preferred-Value field when appearing in a record whose Type is "variant":

> - For fields of type 'script', 'region', or 'variant', 'Preferred-Value' contains the subtag of the same type that is preferred for forming the language tag.

My initial interpretation of this was that if the Type of the record is *variant,* then the value of a Preferred-Value is also a *variant* — "a subtag of the same type". In other words, I read "of the same type" as "of the same type as the record itself".

However, there are records in the current version of the [language tag registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) (2018-04-23 at the time I write this — it doesn’t seem there are versioned links) which do not match this interpretation. For example:

```
Type: variant
Subtag: arevela
Description: Eastern Armenian
Added: 2006-09-18
Deprecated: 2018-03-24
Preferred-Value: hy
Prefix: hy
```

The Preferred-Value here is not a variant — a variant must be either 5-8 alphanumeric ASCII characters or 1 digit plus three alphanumeric characters. In this case in particular, it’s clear that it’s referring to the Armenian language (the first segment of a language tag) rather than to a variant.

However, when looking through other entries, most Preferred-Value values do conform to my initial interpretation. For example:

```
Type: region
Subtag: YD
Description: Democratic Yemen
Added: 2005-10-16
Deprecated: 1990-08-14
Preferred-Value: YE
```

Here, Preferred-Value does appear to be another region code. The rules for script/region/variant types are given together — the Preferred-Value is the "same type" for all of these. If for a region record a "same type  Preferred-Value" means "also a region", how is it that for a variant record Preferred-Value may point at a different type? More importantly, if this is possible, is the only way to determine the type of the Preferred-Value field to test its grammar?

Comment: I’m beginning to suspect the registry just doesn’t conform to its own specification. I just found another, different case: the extlang entry for subtag lsg is missing its Preferred-Value field, which according to the spec must exist and must have the same value as its Subtag.

Comment: Same for extlang "rsi" and extlang "yds". These all share in common being added/updated after 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. That `arevela` entry does not conform to the registry specification. It seems as though they noticed this; the registry as of 2021-02-23 has a new entry for `arevela` without that `Preferred-Value`. It instead has the comment "Preferred tag is hy".

Your comments also seems to be correct (and my initial interpretation of the [section in the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646#section-3.1.7) was wrong). They've changed those entries too, so all extlangs now have a `Preferred-Value` that is a primary language subtag identical to the extlang.